# Using Canonical Correlation Analysis (instead of EFA/PCA) to reduce the dimensionality of two sets of variables prior to clustering/classification

Tags: classification, clustering, canonical-correlation

I have two sets of paired continuous data obtained from two tests. My goal is to answer the following research questions:

**Q1.** To what extent can results on one test be used to predict the results on the other?

**Q2.** Does the underlying population comprise a single homogeneous group or does it comprise distinct clusters?

**Q3.** If there are clusters, can the clusters be better delineated by combining information from both data sets, as opposed using information from just one or the other?

To answer Q1, am using canonical correlation analysis (CCA); in my case I get two significant canonical components. However to answer Q2 and Q3, ***would it be valid to perform cluster analysis on these canonical components*** (analogous to clustering principal components or latent factors)? I haven't been able to find clear examples of cluster analysis following CCA in the literature.

To be a little more specific, my approach for this particular study when dealing with just one set of data is pretty standard. I run EFA or PCA to reduce the dimensionality, and then use some form of clustering (K-Means, Hierarchical, Gaussian Mixtures, etc.). The reliability of the clusters can be assessed by internal metrics (e.g. the silhouette score for K-Means). I believe that this isn't enough, and some kind of external evaluation is needed. For this there are almost limitless approaches; I've tried building a classifier (e.g. using linear discriminant analysis) from the labels returned by the cluster analysis, and then evaluating the classification error through cross-validation. What I would like to know is: ***Can a similar approach be taken when the initial dimension reduction step involves CCA on two datasets instead of EFA/PCA on one dataset?***

I hope the question is clear, if any clarification is needed I will try my best to provide it. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: The general answer is "yes" or "why not?" Canonical variates are just some (new) variables; you may build your future analysis on them. On the other hand, one must keep in mind what concept these variables represent or how they were derived. Canonical variates were extracted in order to account for the correlatedness between the sets. It's different meaning than principal components (accounting for variance) or EFA (accounting for pairwise correlations and variance). All the subsequent analyses results therefore are not comparable in cases of CCA vs PCA/EFA.

Comment: ... (strictly speaking, even in cases of PCA vs EFA they aren't quite comparable).